# Traveling from Portoroz, Slovenia to Ljubljana airport on Sunday morning

Tags: airport-transfer, slovenia, ljubljana

I have a return flight on Sunday, 12 March, from Ljubljana airport. I plan to be at the seaside that weekend, either in Portoroz or Piran.

The issue is that my flight if fairly early, I need to be at the airport at 10am. How can I get there, fast and cheap, from Portoroz or Piran (or anywhere close by)?

Comment: OT, but you really, really want to be in Piran, not Portoroz, if you have the option. Piran is charming and calm, Portoroz mass-tourism dumpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a taxi may be your only choice. [Here](http://www.airportljubljana.co/Taxi_transfer_from_Portoroz.php) is one for €120. Less should be possible if you can pair up with another or others, and asking in Portorož or Piran might turn up something a little cheaper. You would need to be departing around 08:30.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am still hoping to find something cheaper than that. One can easily forget that smaller countries don't have trains and busses running all the time.

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but still can be useful for some people in the future.
We have public transports, such as railway and buses, which you can check most at:

**railways**
http://www.slo-zeleznice.si/en/

**buses**
https://www.ap-ljubljana.si/en/

The **third option** is https://prevoz.org which is paralel to https://www.blablacar.com but it's used mostly for inside traffic through Slovenia, but its waaaaaay cheaper. You can get nearly anywhere from Ljubljana for 5€. For different cities to others the price may vary, but it's always between 3€ and 10€.